# Exclude items from Array.map()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to exclude items that contain `Packages` in `packageData.type`. To show only the `packageData` that has items with `packageData.type` as `Add-on`.

Array is as example

```
{
  "packageData": [
    {
      "title": "Title 1",
      "type": [
        "Packages"
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Title 2",
      "type": [
        "Add-on"
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Title 3",
      "type": [
        "Add-on"
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Title 4",
      "type": [
        "Add-on"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and this is how I am currently trying to remove results which is giving zero results.

```
<ul>
  {packageData.map(function() {
    if (packageData.type ==! "Packages") {
     return (
      <li key={packageData.id}>
        <a>
          <img src={packageData.heroImage.sizes.src} alt=""/>
          <h3>{packageData.title}</h3>
        </a>
      </li> );
    } else {
      return null;
    };
  })}
</ul>
```

How can I make this work? Or should I be filtering these results prior to displaying and then `map` the returned items?

Comment: [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Why not just use `filter`? It returns an array as well.

Comment: You can simply use the javascript's filter prototype

Comment: Your `type` property contains an array. Comparing a string to an array will never yield true.

Comment: Thank you all - there I was over complicating things. My `array` is slightly more complex than the example shown but you've put me on the right path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use filter before map, Filter will filter the array and then map will iterate through array. Below is the sample code

```js
var data = {
  "packageData": [
    {
      "title": "Title 1",
      "type": [
        "Packages"
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Title 2",
      "type": [
        "Add-on"
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Title 3",
      "type": [
        "Add-on"
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Title 4",
      "type": [
        "Add-on"
      ]
    }
  ]
};

data.packageData.filter((item) => { return item.type[0] !== 'Packages' }).map((item)=> { console.log(item); });
```

Comment: OP says he specifically wants only the `Add-On` types to be shown rather than "not `Packages`". If another type is added, this code will break - you should instead check that `item.type.indexOf("Add-On") !== -1`